# Did Rock Lee learn the Leaf Dragon God?

Tags: naruto

It seemed that Master Chen refused to teach Lee the Leaf Dragon God.

Later on in the series, it appears that Lee was able to use the move anyway. How is this possible? Did he learn it from somewhere else? And is this move part of Lee's cannon? Or is just me getting filler mixed up with cannon?

Comment: please describe more

Comment: What do you mean? it means that has Lee learned the Leaf Dragon God technique?

Comment: More often than not, we need to know some background/the motivation why a question is asked, i.e. is there something that conflicts with another fact? So, could you at least expand the question regarding that?

Comment: I believe anything with Master Chen in it is all filler anyway.  So ... make up a head-cannon answer?

Comment: But a technique could be used in the later series, so filler or not, did he learn it?

Comment: I editted the question based on the context of the comments. Please review it and let's discuss it further. I think this question can be fixed and possibly answered.

Comment: I think he could learn it just by observing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a filler episode.

From [here](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Leaf_Dragon_God) you can see that it is present in the anime only, with no reference in the manga. Also can you specify in which episode of naruto/boruto Lee used that move. Apart from the filler there is no mention of that move in any other episodes.

Also check [here](http://www.animefillerlist.com/shows/naruto-shippuden) to see which episodes are filler and which are not.